# If column A equals column B then return value in column C

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with different database cuts of data as it existed in a past stage and a current stage.

I want to see if "Company A" in column A who was in the Negotiation stage in Column B now exists as "Company A" in column C (a subset of Column A) that is now in a Closed Won stage in column D.  If this is the case, I want to return a $ amount value in Column E.

Ignoring my specific scenario, the core logic I need is if column A equals column B then return the value in column C.

Comment: `=IF(A1=B1,C1,"")` unless I'm missing something. Why is this a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> =IF(condition, value if true, value if false)

check [this](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-if-statement/), so

```
=IF(A1=B1, C1, "")
```

for example

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response (without the snarky comment like JoeMalpass).  I dont get into Excel much and was traveling down the VLOOKUP route, which explains why my attempts to look this up weren't working.